# rails 3.1, using controller/view generator getting 'uninitialized constant Haml::Rails::Application (NameError)'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am attempting to use HAML with rails and have views be generated with HAML instead of ERB.

I added:

```
gem 'haml'
gem 'haml-rails'
```

to my Gemfile and did bundle install.

```
$ rails g controller home index
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/script_rails_loader.rb:11: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:136: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
/Users/jrm/src/rails/haml/config/application.rb:14: uninitialized constant Haml::Rails::Application (NameError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:21:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:21
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

Using haml gem seperately works without error, but views generated are ERB and not HAML. How can I configure rails 3.1 to generate HAML views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved - issue was that my lacklustre imagination had me name my rails project *haml*.

Not a good idea.

1. Created a new project (NOT called *haml*)
2. Added to Gemfile:

   ```
   gem 'haml'
   gem 'haml-rails'
   ```
3. Volia views are generated as HAML instead of ERB

   ```
   $ rails g controller home index
         create  app/controllers/home_controller.rb
          route  get "home/index"
         invoke  haml
         create    app/views/home
         create    app/views/home/index.html.haml
   ```

Comment: amazingly, i've done the exact same thing as you and run into the exact same problem. for the very lazy or just too far along, you can also just rename your project with `mv haml new_name` and update the name in `config/application.rb`. or just use the 'rename'  gem